# How to find an integral representation of a solution of a linear ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a linear homogeneous second order ODE $a(x) y'' + b(x) y' + c(x)y = 0$ with some boundary conditions. I am curious if there is a way to deduce an integral representation of the solution. I mean without solving the ODE by some other method, but rather from the ODE itself.

By integral representation I think of something like:

- Bessel function $J_n(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\pi \cos(nt-x\sin(t)) dt$ which solves $x^2y''+xy'+(x^2-n^2)y = 0$, or
- Airy function Ai$(x) = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \cos(\frac{t^3}{3}+xt) dt$ which solves $y''-xy = 0$

It is clear that for each function there are various ways to represent them via an integral. Is there any systematic way to find one from the differential equation alone?

Comment: Using the Euler-Lagrange conditions on $\min_{y}\int (\frac 12 a(x)y'(x)^2-b(x)y(x))dx$ we can obtain ODEs like $a(x)y''(x)+a'(x)y'(x)+b(x)=0$

Comment: I think you understand the question in a wrong way. I did not mean to rewrite the problem using an integral, but rather how to express the solution in terms of an integral.

Answer (score 0):

Chapter II.A-82 from [Zwillinger & Dobrushkin's Handbook of Differential Equations, 4th edition](https://www.routledge.com/Handbook-of-Differential-Equations/Zwillinger-Dobrushkin/p/book/9780367252571) has a nice section about this.

Here's an outline of the general method: Suppose we have Bessel's equation

$$
\begin{equation} 
x y'' + y' + xy = 0
\end{equation}
$$

We seek a solution of the form:

$$ y(x) = \int_{\mathcal{C}} e^{xz} K(z) dz $$
where $z$ is a complex variable and $\mathcal{C}$ is a suitably chosen contour in the complex-plane and $K(z)$ is called the kernel. This is analogous to the Laplace inversion formula if you're familiar with Laplace transforms.

Using this ansatz we can differentiate under the integral sign top get $y'$ and $y''$. Then plugging this back in we get
$$ \int_{\mathcal{C}} \left[ x z^2 + z + x \right] e^{xz} K(z) dz = 0 \ \ \ \forall \ \ \ x$$

Now suppose we could find a function $S(z)$ such that the integrand becomes a total differential, i.e.
$$\frac{d}{dz} \left( e^{xz} S(z) \right)$$
becomes the integrand. This would be fantastic since then Bessel's equation would become:
$$
\begin{align}
0 &= \int_{\mathcal{C}} \frac{d}{dz} \left( e^{xz} S(z) \right) \\
&= e^{xz} S(z) \bigg |_{\partial \mathcal{C}}
\end{align}
$$
and we would just have to choose $\mathcal{C}$ such that this holds. So setting these equal gives
$$\frac{d}{dz} \left( e^{xz} S(z) \right) = \left[ x z^2 + z + x \right] e^{xz} K(z) $$
and then equating like-powers of $x$ gives a simple set of $2$ simple differential equations to solve for $S(z)$. Namely,
$$\mathcal{O}(x^0): \ \ \ S'(z) = z K(z)$$
$$\mathcal{O}(x^1): \ \ \ S(z) = (z^2 + 1) K(z)$$
Dividing these two equations gives us $1$ separable ODE which gives us
$$S(z) = \sqrt{z^2 + 1}.$$
This immediately tells us that $K(z) = S/z^2 + 1 = 1/\sqrt{z^2 + 1}$
so now we have
$$y(x) = \int_{\mathcal{C}} \frac{e^{xz}}{\sqrt{z^2 +1 }}$$
$\underline{\text{if}}$ we can find a contour $\mathcal{C}$ such that $e^{xz} S(z)$ equals zero for all x. Note: asymptotic methods can be applied to the above, making integral representations a powerful tool! Anyway, we want
$$e^{xz} \sqrt{z^2 + 1}\bigg|_{\partial \mathcal{C}} = 0 \ \ \ \forall \ \ \ x.$$
One way to achieve this is by choosing endpoints at $\pm i$. But there are many other ways of choosing this contour as well. Let's say we choose $\pm i$, this means
$$y(x) = \int_{-i}^{i} \frac{e^{xz}}{\sqrt{z^2 +1 }} dz$$
solves Bessel's equation! We can of course clean this up a bit. Let $z = i w$ where $|w| \leq 1$, then we have
$$y(x) \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{e^{iwx}}{\sqrt{1-w^2}} i dw.$$

There are two linearly independent solutions hiding in this expression. Let's look just at what's happening at $x=0$. Then we find $y(0) = i \pi$. Bessel's equation in this example for $x \in \mathbb{R}$ takes the form of a constant (call it $A$) times $J_{0}(x)$. And we just found that $y(0) = i \pi$ therefore, $A = i \pi$. This means $y(x) = i \pi J_{0}(x)$, giving
$$J_{0}(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{e^{i wx}}{\sqrt{1 - w^2}} i dw$$
and with the substitution $w = \sin t$ this becomes the more familiar form:
$$ J_{0}(x) = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} \cos(x \sin t) dt$$

Hope this helps!